# Resize an image and upload to server returns in an error code

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

This is my code:

```
var dimensionsArray = []
dimensionsArray.push(new cardSet("L", 1000, 500, 200, 100))
dimensionsArray.push(new cardSet("M", 500, 200, 100, 50))
dimensionsArray.push(new cardSet("S", 200, 100, 50, 20))

function cardSet(name, dimSetWidth, dimSetHeight, dimPreviewWidth, dimPreviewHeight){
    this.name = name
    this.dimSetWidth = dimSetWidth 
    this.dimSetHeight = dimSetHeight
    this.dimPreviewWidth = dimPreviewWidth
    this.dimPreviewHeight = dimPreviewHeight
}
function insertBeforeLastOccurrence(strToSearch, strToFind, strToInsert) {
    var n = strToSearch.lastIndexOf(strToFind);
    if (n < 0) return strToSearch;
    return strToSearch.substring(0,n) + strToInsert + strToSearch.substring(n);    
}
exports.resizeCardSet = functions.storage.object().onChange(event => {
    let file = event.data
    var filePath = event.data.name
    if (file.resourceState === 'not_exists') {
    return;
  }
      if(!filePath.startsWith('admin/')) {
    return;
  }
const fileBucket = event.data.bucket
const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket);
const fileName = filePath.split('/').pop()
const tempFilePath = []
const dimensions = []
const promisesDownloads = []
var q = 0

while (q < dimensionsArray.length){
    let downloadTo = insertBeforeLastOccurrence(`/tmp/${fileName}`, ".png", dimensionsArray[q].name)
    dimensions.push(downloadTo)
    console.log(downloadTo)
    promisesDownloads.push(bucket.file(filePath).download({
  destination: dimensions[q]
}))
    q += 1
}
console.log("1")
return Promise.all([promisesDownloads]).then(() => {
    console.log("2")
   var promises = []
   var downloadDestinations = []
      if (filePath.startsWith('admin/generatenewcardset/')) {
        filePath = filePath.substring(25)
        var setNumber = filePath.match(/\d/g);
        setNumber = setNumber.join("");
        let nameFile = filePath.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
        filePath = 'deckcards/' + setNumber + '/' + nameFile
        if (filePath.indexOf('Set') > -1)
            {
              var q = 0
                while (q < dimensionsArray.length){
                    let downloadTo = 'deckcards/' + setNumber + '/' + nameFile + dimensionsArray[q].name
                    downloadDestinations.push(downloadTo)
                    promises.push(spawn('convert', [dimensions[q], '-resize',  dimensionsArray[q].dimSetHeight + 'x' + dimensionsArray[q].dimSetWidth + '>', dimensions[q]]))
                    q += 1
                }
            }else{
                return
            }
    }
    else{
        return
    }
    console.log("3")

return Promise.all([promises]).then(() => {
    console.log("4")
      var promisesB = []
      var i = 0
      console.log(promises[0])
      for (file in dimensions){
    console.log('Thumbnails created at', dimensions[i])
    promisesB.push(bucket.upload(dimensions[i], {
      destination: downloadDestinations[i]
    }))      
    i += 1
      }
    return Promise.all([promisesB]).then(() => {
        let file = bucket.file(event.data.name)
        return file.delete()
    })
  })
})
})
```

I want to upload 1 image in admin/generatenewcardset and that image should be stored inside another map, in 3 different images.

Only I can upload an image in that map, the image always begins with an number, followed by Set in this example (so: 1Set, 2Set...). I want to store in in deckcards/{numberofset}/Set{dimension}, so it could be: deckcards/2/SetM

Now when I try to upload an image, this is the output:

[image]

This is the full error:

```
ChildProcessError: `convert /tmp/1SetL.png -resize 500x1000> /tmp/1SetL.png` failed with code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/child-process-promise/lib/index.js:132:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:334:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:498:12)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're showing a lot of code here, and a lot of things could be going wrong.  Are you sure that any file is downloading correctly?  Have you verified that the contents are exactly what you expect?  Try trimming down the code to a bare minimum: get a single file to download, verify that its contents are correct, and that a single conversion works.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @DougStevenson yes it is a little bit long... I have tried another approach, with a lot less code which is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44504606/download-and-upload-picture-gives-me-0-bytes-when-using-array only here, the image is 0 bytes... You can reproduce that code very easy. Can you take a look? Thanks!!